# background color on individual h2 tag

Tags: html, css

I am a little bit in doubt of a small thing here. I have made a wireframe, that I started to make. The line: "A catcy piece of text" has to have a background. But how do I make that background, without styling all h2 tags? As I understand it is not good practice to give a h2 tag a class?

[image: Picture]

**HTML**

```
<section class="container-fluid" id="section1">
        <div class="v-center">
            <h1 class="text-center">COMPANY NAME</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center">Change this <b>subline</b> here</h2>
            <p class="text-center">
                <br>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue btn-lg btn-huge lato" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Get Free Membership</a>
            </p>
            <h2 class="text-center">A CATCY PEICE OF TEXT</h2>


            <p class="text-center"><i>Enter your email for more news</i></p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: _"As I understand it is not good practice to give a h2 tag a class"_ That's not correct at all. Completely fine.

Comment: Add an ID there? Check `innerText` (if using JS)? And no, having classes isn't inherently good

Comment: ah okay. Just my boss who said to me the other day. Never give a h2 a class. You have to learn to inherit instead.

Comment: If I fx had to play around with inherit... Then I could give a h2 some style. If I wanted that specific h2 tag to have a background then I could inherit the styles from the h2 tag, and give the specific h2 an individual styles? In case, how should that be done in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ID or even a unique class is fine, nothing wrong with it. But to answer your question without referring to the classes, you need to use the hierarchy of your DOM elements. One such way would be:

```
section > div > p + h2 {...}
```

The says select the h2 element that is the adjacent sibling of a paragraph that is the child of a div that is the child of a section.

Check out the [MDN section on CSS combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know a site where I can read about this hierarchy?

Comment: I added a link at the end of my answer

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer here.